# Office UI Fabric React - DetailsList Columns's width

Tags: office-ui-fabric

How to configure columns in `DetailsList` component so that they align themselves to fit content?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't believe `DetailsList`'s Columns currently support fitting to their contents. Each Column definition takes a `minWidth`, `maxWidth`, and `isResizable` to constrain the column to some dimension while affording the User the ability to resize. There is no wrap to contents or similar property present on the [IColumn interface](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/9110f7bf9e5169d0742dda7210da761ccdfd8e87/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/DetailsList/DetailsList.types.ts#L292). [Here's an example](https://codepen.io/dzearing/pen/XRvXoL).

Comment: Agree. I faced the same issue, but workaround was the set of column's min/max only.

Answer (score 0):

```
return [...staticColumns, ...visibleColumns.map(c => {
    return  {
        key: c.Name,
        name: c.Title,
        fieldName: c.Name, 
        minWidth: 100,
        isResizable: true,
        isCollapsible: true,
        onRender: (item: any, index: number, column: IColumn) => {
          column.minWidth = 20;
          return <span>{item[c.Name]}</span>;
        },
    } as IColumn;
})];
```

First set initial minWidth: 100, then change to 20 in the onRender callback. It's work for me

Answer (score -1):

u can use maxWidth property to set the column width.

```
function buildColumns(
  item,
  canResizeColumns,
  onColumnClick,
  sortedColumnKey,
  isSortedDescending,
  groupedColumnKey,
  isMultiline
) {
  const columns = [];

  if (item) {
    for (const propName in item) {
      if (item.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
        columns.push({
          key: propName,
          name: item[propName].name,
          fieldName: propName,
          minWidth: MIN_COLUMN_WIDTH,
          maxWidth: item[propName].width,
        });
      }
    }
  }

  return columns;
}
```